# How do emoticons and hashags affect the accuracy of Google Natural Language Classify Text?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, google-natural-language

I have a project where I have to find categories of text using google natural language classify text.

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents/classifyText

My text documents will be having emoticons and hashtags. 
Can anyone tell me how these will affect the score? Should I get rid of them before calling the API or let them be?

I have tried multiple documents by myself and am getting conflicting results. Can anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly for text-classification, but for sentiment detection, I don't believe it does account for emojis

The sentences:

1. "What a day! I am so happy about the way things turned out "
2. "What a day! I am so happy about the way things turned out"

both receive the **same** +0.9 score and 1.8 magnitude.
(You can try it out for yourself [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language#natural-language-api-demo))